# Export local term set with PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, managed-metadata

I created a managed metadata column on a document library. How can I export this local term set with PowerShell?

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to do this

1. Easiest way is to Export Term Stores in a .csv file and then Import them to target server.

   [Export using CSV](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/thirusrinivasan1/2015/09/28/sharepoint-exportimport-managed-metadata-terms-through-csv/)

The major drawback of this is that it does not persist the GUID of the terms.

2. Second way is using PowerShell create a .cab file to import on target server

> Here is the powershell script to export managed metadata to .cab file

```
$mmsApplication = Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
$mmsProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}
Export-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData $mmsApplication.Id -ServiceProxy $mmsProxy -Path "\\SERVER_NAME\PATH\TO\ExportedMetadata.cab"
```

> For Import

```
$mmsApplication = Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
$mmsProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}
Import-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData $mmsApplication.Id -ServiceProxy $mmsProxy -Path "\\SERVER_NAME\PATH\TO\ExportedMetadata.cab" -OverwriteExisting
```

3. You can use import / export tool to migrate the term set like http://termsetimporter.codeplex.com/

Comment: Number 1 looks good but I also need the GUID (and hierarchy). Any other ideas?

Comment: If you need GUID then go with the second approach

Comment: But I need the data in one list to do some reports. I don't want do import the metadata to another site. With the second one I have no list with the complete structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a fantastic couple of PowerShell scripts that can Import and Export Terms, Term sets, and Term groups..

This also includes all Custom Shared Properties (Which is amazing!)

[Exporting Link](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/exporting-taxonomy-from-sharepoint-using-powershell/) | [Exporting Link (Google Cache)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3A%2F%2Fcann0nf0dder.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F12%2Fexporting-taxonomy-from-sharepoint-using-powershell%2F&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=cache%3A%2F%2Fcann0nf0dder.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F12%2Fexporting-taxonomy-from-sharepoint-using-powershell%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4294j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[Importing Link](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/importing-taxonomy-to-sharepoint-using-powershell/) | [Importing Link (Google Cache)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3A%2F%2Fcann0nf0dder.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F29%2Fimporting-taxonomy-to-sharepoint-using-powershell%2F&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=cache%3A%2F%2Fcann0nf0dder.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F29%2Fimporting-taxonomy-to-sharepoint-using-powershell%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1108j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)